# asp.net javascript ajax error: not found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Trying to send ajax message fails with message:

[image]

My simple aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.AspNetForms.ReportViewer" %>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CleanUpSession() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ReportViewer.aspx/CleanUp",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button OnClick="CleanUpSession();">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

cs code:

```
public partial class ReportViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string CleanUp()
    {
        return "My message";
    }

}
```

If url changed "ReportViewer.aspx/CleanUp" to "~/AspNetForms/ReportViewer.aspx/CleanUp" then i catch exception

> "The file '/AspNetForms/~/AspNetForms/ReportViewer.aspx' does not exist."

Comment: try `data: {},`

Comment: same result, even if remove 'data' line, error persist

Comment: actually your original code is more correct w.r.t. data - although I thought jquery would jsonify the data anyway

Comment: so the current error says it does not exists right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. Just used asp:button instead of simple button and ajax

```
<body onbeforeunload="CleanUpSession();">
<script type="text/javascript">
function CleanUpSession() {
    var item = document.getElementById('<%=ButtonCleanUp.ClientID%>');
    if (item != null)
        item.click();
}
    </script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="ButtonCleanUp" OnClick="CleanUp_Click" Text="Button Text" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Script tag is placed incorrectly in your markup.

Try this

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="stackoverflow1.ReportViewer" %>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CleanUpSession() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ReportViewer.aspx/CleanUp",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button OnClick="CleanUpSession();">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```